# Ferrite rod (loopstick) antenna directivity

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, coil, ferrite

In a [video about ferrite rod antennas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udLa7dZC0ts) it was stated that the antenna is most  sensitive to the direction perpendicular to the axis of the rod, and it is insensitive along the axis. These are shown with the green markers in the screenshot below. I found it surprising, because the induced voltage is equal to the change in the magnetic flux, which goes through the loop (the scalar product of the magnetic flux with the normal vector of the "surface"). Where is the mistake? Which argument is the correct one?

All the literature I've found was either very high level, or formulate the explanation in a very scientific, complex, mathematical way, with lots of backreferences, which I was not able to fully trace back and understand.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-magnetic-field-lines-around-a-straight-current-carrying-conductor

Comment: @Antonio51 I am not sure how the link is relevant, since the question was about small loop antennas, not about a straight conductor. Could you elaborate it?

Comment: The ferrite you use is the "receiver". The "transmitter" is generally an "vertical" antenna which is a "dipole" ... So "lines" of field "H" are circular around the emitting antenna.

Comment: For the "navigation" with the radio-compass, we also use, as a reference, a vertical antenna to "remove doubt".

Comment: A propagating radio wave consists of electric and magnetic field vectors, both perpendicular to the direction of travel. The small ferrite/coil antenna is most sensitive to magnetic fields along the ferrite rod's axis, therefore it's most sensitive to waves arriving from directions perpendicular to the rod's axis.

Comment: Just to check if I got it right: So a horizontal rod antenna will work *only* with a vertically positioned dipole antenna (the conductor is vertical), right? And the rod should be placed vertical if the dipole was horizontal.

Comment: Yes. Just so. Remember that it is in "far-field approximation", in "near-field", it is a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For help understanding, one can find here some good simulations about antenna (transmitting)... and others things.

http://amanogawa.com/archive/Antenna1/Antenna1-2.html

[image]

One can see that the H vector is "circular" around the antenna.

So, for receiving something, "ferrite rod" must be "perpendicular" to the "direction line" of the emitter.

NB: This is the reason why two inductors that must **not be "coupled"** magnetically are **arranged perpendicular** to each other.